# How could I make a good application architecture in Python with PyQt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I think my appication doesn't have a good architecture. I can't figure out how to navigate between files correctly.

Here is a non-standardized schema of my application.

[image]

Each file contains one class.

The principal problem is that I can't get some variables from any class to another because of the architecture of the code.
If I put all my classes in one file, it will certainly runs but I want to separate all my classes (which are `QWindow`and `QWidget`) in several files.

Comment: That diagram provides virtually no insight into how your application actually works. There must be thousands of different ways in which it could be realised in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** In every parent class, import each child with :

```
from childfilename import childclassname
```

For example, in the optionwindow class, you will have :

```
from mainwindowfilename import mainwindowclassname
from toolbarfilename import toolbarsclassname
from menubarfilename import menubarclassname
```

*Note 1 : For better lisibility, name your files with the same name as your classes.*
*for example : mytoolbar.py contains `class mytoolbar(QtGui.QToolBar)*`

*Note 2 : You need to place an empty **__init__.py** in every folder that contains a class)*

*Note 3 : You can place classes in different folders. If you do so, use :*

```
from folder.childfilename import childclassname
```

**2.** To instantiate and call child functions or get child variables :

In the parent class :

```
self.child1=childclassname()
self.child1.childfunction1()
a1 = self.child1.childvariable1
```

In the child class :

```
...
self.childvariable1 = 2
def childfunction1(self):
    ...
```

**3.** To get parent or grand-parents variables or functions in child :
In the parent class :

```
...
self.parentvariable1 = 2
def parentfunction1(self):
    ...
```

In the child class :

```
self.parent().parentfunction1()`
a1 = self.parent().parentvariable1`
```

*Note : self.parent().parent(). ... will get you to the grand parent.*

I hope it helped